# Count page numbers with DocuSign PHP SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the PHP SDK to create and send documents. I need to insert initial here on all pages, except the signature pages.

The content of the document is variable, it can have at least 7/8 pages. So I believe that using templates is not interesting.

Is there a way to place the initial here on all pages, without knowing the number of pages?

Is it possible to count the number of pages before sending the document?

What solution could you apply?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make an API call to get all the documents meta-data which include the number of pages in each document.
When you add an initial tab (or any tab) you get to set the page number.
So that's the simple approach I would use. Add it to pages 1 .. n-1 and find n by making another API call.

PHP call:

```
envelopes_api->getEnvelopes($account_id, $envelope_id);
```